# Google Cloud Node Js Start Module not found

Tags: json, node.js, google-cloud-platform

I am trying to deploy an application to Google Cloud. However i get the following error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/src/server/mainServer.js'
```

The package.json contains the following:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node /src/server/mainServer.js"
},
```

The package.json file is contained in the base directory alongside the src folder.

EDIT: Structure:

```
app /
    package.json
    src /
        server /
            mainServer.js
        client /
            app.js
```

After changing the path to ./ I get the error:

```
Error: Cannot find module '/app/src/server/mainServer.js'
```

Comment: Can you paste your project directory structure.

Comment: Can you move `package.json` out of app directory.

Comment: Where to? I didnt create the app directory. Google cloud does that

Comment: One other thing to do will be to put your `package.json` inside your server folder and `"start": "node mainServer.js"`

Answer (score 0):

Try to place a period before the directory folder.

That is: `'./src'` instead of `'/src'`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/server/mainServer.js"
},
```

Answer (score 0):

Make it an absolute path by adding `.`. This means walk up the directory tree from the current working directory of `package.json`

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/server/mainServer.js"
}
```